# plotting data frame grouped by multiple columns

Tags: python, plot

I have a data frame called crs which looks like below:

```
| Brand | Mark | Milage |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| A  | w   | 100k |
| A  | w   | 220k |
| A  | v  | 250k |
| A  | v   | 100k |
| B  | s   | 120k |
| B  | t   | 190k |
| B  | t   | 200k |
| C  | u  | 160k |
| C  | u   | 170k |
```

In order to plot the min milage per brand, I did

`min_dist_each_brand=crs.groupby('brand', as_index=False).agg({'milage': 'min'})`

then

`min_dist_each_brand.plot(x='brand', kind='bar')`

If I want to plot the same thing per 'Mark', I repeat the same code while replacing 'brand' with 'Mark'. But I want to be able to plot min_dist per brand or mark without making new data frame.
I know I can do groupby multiple columns as follows;

`min_dist=crs.groupby(by=['brand', 'mark']).agg({'milage': 'min'})`

Is there anyway I can plot minimum milage per brand and mark using this new min_dist data frame?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To show both the brand and the mark as a graph, you will need two levels of x-axis labels. The first (mark) can be obtained from the level 1 index and set as xticklables. The second level is a little bit manual. As there are 5 minima with two each for A, B and one for C, I have split the location of the second label as 0.2, 0.6 and 0.9, so that they are in between the ticks (for A and B), while right under the tick for C. The -0.1 will adjust the height of the second label.

```
min_dist=crs.groupby(by=['brand', 'mark']).agg({'milage': 'min'})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
min_dist.plot(kind='bar', xlabel='', ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(min_dist.index.get_level_values(level=1).tolist(), rotation=0)

for i in range(len(min_dist)):
    if i == 0: #For A label
        ax.text(0.2, -0.1, min_dist.index.get_level_values(level=0)[0], ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
    elif i == 2: #For B label
        ax.text(0.6, -0.1, min_dist.index.get_level_values(level=0)[2], ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
    elif i == 4: #For C label
        ax.text(0.9, -0.1, min_dist.index.get_level_values(level=0)[4], ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
plt.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]

EDIT: To ONLY show the brand in the axis labels, you will need to set the first level to blank by changing the `xticklabels` to []. Also, as the second level may seem rather far away from plot. So, you can bring closer to the axis by reducing the position from `-0.1` to say `-0.05`.

Further, just for fun, I added a different color for each brand. So, the A will be reds, B will be Blues and C will be greens. If not required, feel free to not use that code.. or change the colors in `mymap` to colors of your liking.

**Updated code**

```
min_dist=crs.groupby(by=['brand', 'mark']).agg({'milage': 'min'})

## Create new column and map colors to what you want in them
mymap = {'A': 'red', 'B':'green', 'C':"blue"}
min_dist['mycolor'] = min_dist.index.get_level_values(0).map(mymap)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

min_dist.milage.plot(kind='bar', xlabel='', color = mycolor, ax=ax)
#ax.set_xticklabels(min_dist.index.get_level_values(level=1).tolist(), rotation=0)
ax.set_xticklabels([]) ## Changed to blanks, so that first level will not be shown
ax.legend().remove()

for i in range(len(min_dist)):  ##Update - reduced y-spacing from -0.1 to -0.05
    if i == 0: #For A label
        ax.text(0.2, -0.05, min_dist.index.get_level_values(level=0)[0], ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
    elif i == 2: #For B label
        ax.text(0.6, -0.05, min_dist.index.get_level_values(level=0)[2], ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
    elif i == 4: #For C label
        ax.text(0.9, -0.05, min_dist.index.get_level_values(level=0)[4], ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to show just brand using the data frame "min_dist"? When I try min_dist.plot(x='brand', kind='bar'), I gives me key error 'brand'. I know we can show only brand if I make a data frame grouped by just brand. But I want to have data frame grouped by both brand and mark for future use.

Comment: Updated response...